# What do all these download bar colors mean when I'm watching a streaming video?

Tags: utorrent

I was watching a video while I was downloading it today when I noticed all these colors in the download bar:

[image: the download bars with an orange freehand circle highlighting a green/white/red bar overlapping the downloaded sections and a red line on it]

I've figured out that the red line on the left corresponds with my video playback, but the multi-color bar seems to jump back and forth too when I restart the video. What does it all mean?

Answer (score 7):

You’re not the only one who has wondered that, unfortunately [this question has not been given an answer](http://forum.dev.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=105888).

I just Googled for `utorrent color bar` and lo and behold, the very first search result was a [thread](https://www.google.com/search?q=utorrent%20color%20bar) I started several years ago asking for a key/legend for the colors.

At the time, they responded with a link to a section of the [FAQ](http://www.utorrent.com/help/faq#What_do_the_colors_in_the_Availability_graph_mean.3F) which explained what each color means in each of the UI elements, but unfortunately that is no longer present.

Instead, today the answer can be found in a [forum post](https://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=102850) (figure 1).

Note however that as of version 2.2, they [finally](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=2051) [decided](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=86384) to add the ability to customize colors when creating a [skin](http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/createskin) (figure 2).

I can’t seem to find the specific colors from your screenshot in the list, so either you are using a skin or they have changed the defaults.

**Figure 1**: µTorrent color key/legend

[image]

**Figure 2**: Customized µTorrent colors scheme

[image]

Comment: @kotekzot, yes, I know. Did you look at the [page](https://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=102850) I linked to? It has a comprehensive list of all colors used in µTorrent, but they are not specifically labeled with obvious names, so it’s not clear which ones they are. Like I said, the colors in the OP’s screenshot (#50FF50,#FFFF70,#FF7080) are not actually present in the list, nor is the green color (#FF7080) of their progress bar, so they are probably using a skin. I don’t use µTorrent 2.2+, so I can’t check the defaults.

Comment: They are obviously download/buffering-related. There is [no clear, exact answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=utorrent+stream+bar+colors+red+yellow+green+-askmefast), so this answer may be the best you’ll get. (Of course one could try re-asking on the µTorrent forums or bumping the [existing question](http://forum.dev.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=105888).) Wait, nevermind, I just did it.

Comment: I'm not using any skin or changed any colors.

Comment: Then they must have changed the default colors. Either way, they don’t seem to be interested in explaining that little bar, at least not yet; the feature is still pretty new, so they may simply not have had time to update the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this myself, unfortunately no official answer has been released by anyone other than the occasional user.

Based on what I could find, the bar will change colors in response to the number of connections you currently have for any given torrent. Usually the bar is not one solid color, but fragmented green and white strips (to show the available torrent pieces, such as the top picture in the question) If there is less than 256 connections. Once you hit this number, the bar can turn a different color to signify the health of the download.

For instance, once you have exactly 256 connections, the bar will turn a solid yellow. It moves through different colors such as brown, cyan, blue, pink and purple in no particular order. I can say for sure than any number of connections past about 450 will result in a bright pink solid color, though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think the green color shows the parts of the item you are downloading. And the blank parts tell that there are some more parts that is not available for downloading, i.e. you are not actually downloading the full version.The bar would be entirely green if you are downloading the full version.